# aws lambda giving "Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY" when connecting to neo4j

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, neo4j, cypher

i am trying to connect to my neo4j db in lambda function. but keeps getting the "Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY" error. but all seems fine when sending requesting in webapp using same parameters. Here's my request body:

```
  var request = {"statements": 
    [
        {
        "statement": "MATCH (p:COMPANY {id: " + event.ID + "})<-[:MADE_BY]-(FRANCHISE) RETURN FRANCHISE"
        }
    ]
  };
  var options = {
      host: hostname,
      path: pathname,
      method: 'POST',
      port: portnumber,
      headers: {
          "Authorization": authInfo,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(request)
      },
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
          console.log('No more data in response.');
      });
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify(request));
  req.end();
```

also tried print out the `JSON.stringify(request)` result but it seems ok to me.

Comment: So from my point of view the JS side seams to be fine. Should be an issue with Statement itself, but i can't help there.

Comment: @Tobi I'm not sure. I'm using the same request body in fetch and everthing went well. In lambda only http is available

Comment: maybe you need to paste the lamda's code as well, maybe there is an issue with a variable inside the closure that is hidden by an other variable (or something else).

Comment: @Tobi full request code updated

Comment: never mind :) just saw that the request object is provided at the second last line. Which framework are you using for the http logic?
And maybe using your browsers dev tools to inspect the actual request's header and body might give you a clue.

Comment: @Tobi i have tried to change the request body to incorrect format, like changing the value in key statements from array to object, there will be correct error message returned, so i don't think the request object is missing…

Comment: As i don't have a clue from neo4j, i think i won't be able to help from this point on. As JS seems to be fine you might need to dig more into the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Buffer.byteLength(request)`, you are passing the `request` object itself instead of the JSON-stringified form of that object. This causes the `Content-Length` header value to be too small.

Try this instead:

```
  var request = {"statements": [ {
        "statement": "MATCH (p:COMPANY {id: {event_id} })<-[:MADE_BY]-(FRANCHISE) RETURN FRANCHISE",
        "parameters": {
          "event_id": event.ID
        }
    } ]
  };
  var request_str = JSON.stringify(request);
  var options = {
      host: hostname,
      path: pathname,
      method: 'POST',
      port: portnumber,
      headers: {
          "Authorization": authInfo,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(request_str)
      },
  };
  console.log(request_str);
  var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
          console.log('No more data in response.');
      });
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
  });

  req.write(request_str);
  req.end();
```

Notice also that this code passes `event.ID` as a parameter, which is more efficient if this code will be called repeatedly.